# Html.DropDownList size attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

This is HTML

```
<select size="25" style="width:100px" id="yearList"/>
```

This is Razor ( not sure if this is the correct term)

```
@Html.DropDownList("yearList", null, new{style="width:100px;"})
```

Does anyone know how to give the Razor version a size attribute similar to the HTML version?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "yearList", 
    Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(),  // <!-- TODO: bind with a real data
    new { 
        size = "25", 
        style = "width: 60px" 
    }
)
```

Comment: `size="5"` is more, so i used `new {style = "width:270px;height:30px" }` and it worked. thank you.

Comment: In case it helps anyone: I wasn't sure what to do with: 
"Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(),  // <!-- TODO: bind with a real data" 
but I found that I could use this syntax:
(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.yearList

Answer (score 1):

open /Content/Site set the select class with the width, this will automatically be reflected on your page

```
select
{
    width:250px;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. `size` attr is number of lines, not the width.